# Java: Compare 3 numbers. Get the greatest of them

Tags: java, numbers

I do have an ArrayList with numbers and I need to get the greatest of them. I thought this would actually solve the problem, but it doesn't for negative numbers since greatest equals 0... Any help?

---

```
    public static int greatest(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    int greatest = 0;

    for (int k : list)
        greatest = Math.max(k, greatest);

    return greatest;
```

---

Comment: Initialise `greatest = Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: What behaviour do you want on zero-length arrays?

Comment: `return list.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);`

Comment: You can initialize greatest with the first element of your list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution is to start with the first element from your list or collection. This has the extra benefit that is type independent.

Make sure you handle 0 size array regardless of how you decide to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Get the first element of the list and make that the greatest.

```
int greatest = list.get(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize greatest to minimum value of an integer as:

```
int greatest = -2147483648;
```

Comment: There's a constant [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) for this. You don't need to put magic numbers in the code.